# Ошибка TypeError: array is undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня такой кусок кода:

```
var housingType = document.querySelector('#housing-type');

function findOfferType(array) { // array - данные из json-файла

    var test = array.map(function(type) {return type.offer.type;});

    housingType.addEventListener('click', function () {
      modifyText();
    });
    
    function modifyText() {
      console.log(test);
    }
}
```

Все работает, только в консоли ошибка:

> TypeError: array is undefined

Подскажите, что именно написано коряво.

Comment: нет там данных из json файла, пишет

Comment: Чтобы понять, в чём проблема, нужно знать, как вызывается `findOfferType()`, с каким аргументом.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt "Бэз аргумэнтов."

Comment: @Igor `findOfferType(undefined, foo)` :)

Comment: Всем спасибо, нашла баг. Функция findOfferType() вызывалась в 2-х местах.